# Application with JSON working on emulator but not on the actual device (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: json, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, device

Im having a problem with my application. When I run it on the VS 2013 emulator it works fine but when I try to run it on a device it shows me an error: "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference". Can anyone tell me why?

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetAsync("json")
          .ContinueWith((taskwithresponse) =>
          {
              var response = taskwithresponse.Result;
              var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              jsonString.Wait();
              dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString.Result);
              Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(() =>
              {

                  List.ItemsSource = content.value.items; //Here is an error

                  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                  {
                      if (content.value.items[i].description[0] == '<')
                      {
                          string input = content.value.items[i].description;
                          content.value.items[i].description = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("/a>") + 3);
                      }
                  }

              })).AsTask().Wait();
          });

    }
```

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Key="Value" 
        ItemsPath="Value" 
      Source="{Binding}"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Text="{Binding title}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                           Foreground="White" 
                           FontSize="20"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="text1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="{Binding pubDate}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           Margin="0" 
                           Grid.Row="1" 
                           FontStyle="Italic"
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="567*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="List" 
              Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20.167,20,53" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              IsTapEnabled="True"
              ItemClick="listView_ItemClick"
              SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged"
              DataContext="bindingUsage"

              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Value}}"   
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SampleDataTemplate}"
        />

</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the List? in List.ItemsSource ??

Comment: Seems like `List` simply is null on this line. Btw, where is your `InitializeComponent();` called anyway? This method should be called first in the constructor because it initializes the XAML components so that e.g. your List is not null. Seems like you removed this important auto-generated line ;)

Comment: InitializeComponent(); is there. I just removed it by accident here. I will edit it in a sec.

Comment: Do you have some sort of binding in your ListView? Can you show us the code of your ListView?

Comment: Here it is. Take a look now.

Comment: I would strongly advise about doing this kind of treatment in the page constructor. You should rather use the `Loaded` event instead.

Comment: I just reproduced your code and I have no problems neither in the emulator or in the device.
As @KooKiz suggested, you should move your code to the Loaded event instead. But I can't seem to find any reason for that problem to be happening.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try it in a second.